# A provider is not being created or called, but other is

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm trying to have multiple `ChangeNotifierProvider` in my app, and the first one I created works great, but when I literally copied over the code into another provider the second one will not work. I've tried nesting them, only creating the second one and using a `MultiProvider`.

Here is my `main`:

```
runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
  ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ArticleProvider()),
  ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CategoryProvider()),
], child: const InsidanApp()));
```

My first provider:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
...

class ArticleProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  /* Data handling and stuffs */

  /// Fetch articles from the API.
  Future<void> fetchArticles() async {
    print('fetchArticles()');
    // Calculate page number.
    const perPage = 50;
    final page = (_articles.length / perPage).ceil() + 1;

    // Fetch articles from API.
    final newArticles =
        await ArticleService.fetchArticles(page: page, count: perPage);
    addAll(newArticles);
    print('Fetched ${newArticles.length} articles.');
  }

  /// Constructor.
  ArticleProvider() {
    print('ArticleProvider()');
    fetchArticles();
  }
}
```

My second provider:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
...

class CategoryProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  /* Data handling stuff. */

  /// Fetch categories from the API.
  Future<void> fetchCategories() async {
    final newCategories = await CategoryService.fetchCategories();
    addAll(newCategories);
  }

  /// Constructor.
  CategoryProvider() {
    fetchCategories();
  }
}
```

Do you have any ideas for what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MultiProvider(providers: [
  ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: ArticleProvider()),
  ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: CategoryProvider()),
]

Try it this way to see if it works.
```

Comment: That works great! Thank you! I'm still fairly new to Flutter and Dart.